# How to handle error on react relay container made by Relay.createContainer?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, relayjs, relay

I made a `react relay container` by [`Relay.createContainer`](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/api-reference-relay-container.html) method.
I want to move user to logout page, when fetching data by GraphQL is failed. So I have to know how to handle error on the container.
I found [`renderFailure`](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/api-reference-relay-root-container.html#renderfailure) in [`Relay.RootContainer`](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/api-reference-relay-root-container.html). But I could not find similar function in [`Relay.createContainer`](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/api-reference-relay-container.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is intended.

A `Container` doesn't fetch data, it only specifies data requirements.
 Thereby, it can't specify what to do on fetch error because it doesn't fetch data.

If you wish to logout the user on fetch error, you have to do this in a `RootContainer`.